# Sharing python program and retrieving any entered data

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am making a python program which sends a communication to customers reminding them about the due date for their insurance premium payment.

I thought of making a small tkinter user interface which takes in date of birth and policy number of the customer for authentication, and then just show a button "Pay" to somewhat represent the payment process. This user interface would be connected to my main python program which runs the mysql database.

Since I am sending an email to the customer reminding him of the payment, it would be obvious to include the payment link also.

So is there a way to create a link and send it in an email, which has the payment interface, and later get back inputted information from that link.

In simple terms, the main program and the backend will remain with me, while  I send a copy of the payment interface to the customer via email. Then there must be some way I can get any inputted information back to me.

All help big and small is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Let us know what you have tried so far and what are the issues faced? Need a prototype code and not a generic problem description

Comment: [email: Examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally, make a link for the download and send it to the person to make the payment. How to make an exe? Use [`pyinstaller`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html), and if the code is big and have dependencies then I would making a setup with [`Inno setup`](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). and upload it to an online storage and send that link of download to the client.

Then with pyinstaller make an exe with a directory.

```
pyinstaller -D -w myscript.py
```

This is to be said in the command prompt.
And then after making a setup, get that setup into a online storage like [Dropbox](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) or [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/) or [Mega](https://mega.nz/).

Anyway keep in mind that to send mails with links maight go into the spam folder. Also this app will give them a warning for virus as the app requires a digital signature that you have to purchase, to make the app not detected by Windows Defender or so.

Apart from all these, you will need a remote database in order to send the data to a database to be accessed by you.

Anyway hope you found this helpful.

Cheers

Comment: @SumathiIyengar also keep in mind, you will need a remote database for it to work globally